# By what mechanisms, other than Hawking Radiation, do black holes lose mass?

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

The equation for the luminosity of a black hole is: $\frac{1}{m^2}\frac{ħc^6}{5120G^2}$.  However, if you take the mass of your black hole, and divide it by the lifetime, the equation you get is: $\frac{1}{m^2}\frac{ħc^6}{15360G^2}$.  These have a constant ratio of $\frac{1}{3}$, leading me to conclude that Hawking Radiation is not the only contributor to the decay of black holes.  What are the other contributors to the decay, if this is known?

Comment: Where did you get your equation for the luminosity $\frac{1}{m^2}\frac{ħc^6}{5120G^2}$? If you assume the black hole is a perfect black body and calculate the luminosity using the Stefan-Boltzmann law you get $\frac{1}{m^2}\frac{ħc^6}{15360G^2}$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer to this question is clearly indicated on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#A_crude_analytic_estimate

Comment: Merger of binary black holes if you consider their total mass

Answer (score 2):

If you take the Hawking temperature, assume the black hole is a perfect emitter and calculate the luminosity using the Stefan-Boltzmann equation the the result is:

$$ P = \frac{ħc^6}{15360 \pi G^2M^2} $$

This calculation is described in detail in [the Wikipedia article on Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#A_crude_analytic_estimate), so I won't go through it in detail here.

But you cannot calculate the lifetime by dividing the rest energy of the black hole ($Mc^2$) by the power because the power is a function of the mass. The power is the rate of decrease of the rest energy so you need to write:

$$ c^2 \frac{dM}{dt} = -\frac{ħc^6}{15360 \pi G^2M^2} $$

Rearranging gives:

$$ \int M^2 dM = -\int \frac{ħc^4}{15360 \pi G^2} dt $$

Integrating and using the boundary condition $M(t=0) = M_0$ gives us:

$$ M^3 = M_0^3 - \frac{ħc^4}{5120 \pi G^2} t $$

The lifetime is then the time at which $M=0$ so we get:

$$ t = \frac{5120 \pi G^2M^3}{ħc^4} $$

Comment: Some caveats:
1. This puts all gray body factors to 1.
2. This assumes the existence of only a single massless scalar boson field.
3. Does this include only the l=m=0 mode of the scalar boson? (or are all modes included? Is that even possible without including the graybody factors?)
The upshot of these caveats is that although this calculation is fine for working out the various scalings, the numerical coefficients should be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reply to the title question:

> By what mechanisms, other than Hawking Radiation, do black holes lose mass?

At the moment , black holes are classical General Relativity objects, represented by a singularity at r=0. The quantum mechanics used in Hawking radiation  is an effective theory. Once gravity has been definitively quantized, one could explore in theory further than the predictions of General Relativity.

At the moment a black hole  cannot emit [gravitational waves,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) because these waves need a mass density and an asymmetric distribution in order to be generated, as is the case with the merging of two black holes [experimentally observed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO).

But as with the effective quantization hypothesized for the inflation period, in the [Big Bang model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)) one could expect that instead of a singularity at r=0 the black hole will have, around the r=0, a similar to the inflation period mass density. In that case, asymmetric distributions of the mass density would radiate gravitational waves. Unfortunately, these would be very weak, due to the weakness of the gravitational interaction. It took the elimination of several  suns masses for gravitational waves to be detectable at LIGO, so it is not possible to suggest an experiment/observation to test this tentative idea.

So  the only way to lose mass through interactions is with the Hawking radiation.